# Information not persisted in a session between two endpoint calls in Jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, express-session, supertest

I’m using express-session to store signin information in the most simple of ways:

```
req.session.userId = user.id
```

I use this configuration for both the development environment in which everything works perfectly, and specifications:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(sessions({
    secret: "secretthatwillbeputinenv",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    resave: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors())
app.use("/", router);
```

*However* when I call a sign_in endpoint using supertest and then call another one which tries to read information persisted using session, no information is actually there. `req.session` correctly returns a session object, but `userId` is null.
How do I make `express-session` work in [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(framework)) without hacks and without mocking anything?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we should know `express-session` will store the session ID in cookies, and find the session data in the memory store (default store) by session ID. So we need to save the session ID cookie and use it in the following requests.

The `supertest` package uses `superagent` underly. You don't need to mock anything.

We should use the [`request.agent()`](https://github.com/ladjs/supertest/blob/v6.3.3/lib/agent.js#L7) method provided by `superagent`. From the [Agents for global state](https://ladjs.github.io/superagent/) documentation:

> In Node SuperAgent does not save cookies by default, but you can use the `.agent()` method to create a copy of SuperAgent that saves cookies

`request.agent()` will create a [cookie jar](https://github.com/ladjs/superagent/blob/v8.0.9/src/node/agent.js#L31) instance (the `CookieJar` class comes from [`cookiejar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookiejar) package). When the HTTP response, it will call the [`Agent.prototype._saveCookies()`](https://github.com/ladjs/superagent/blob/v8.0.9/src/node/agent.js#L66) method to save the cookie to the cookie jar instance.

```js
/**
 * Save the cookies in the given `res` to
 * the agent's cookie jar for persistence.
 *
 * @param {Response} res
 * @api private
 */

Agent.prototype._saveCookies = function (res) {
  const cookies = res.headers['set-cookie'];
  if (cookies) {
    const url = parse(res.request?.url || '')
    this.jar.setCookies(cookies, url.hostname, url.pathname);
  }
};
```

After that, send a new HTTP request, superagent will call the [`Agent.prototype._attachCookies()`](https://github.com/ladjs/superagent/blob/v8.0.9/src/node/agent.js#L81) method to attach the cookie from cookie jar instance to the request.

```js
/**
 * Attach cookies when available to the given `req`.
 *
 * @param {Request} req
 * @api private
 */

Agent.prototype._attachCookies = function (request_) {
  const url = parse(request_.url);
  const access = new CookieAccessInfo(
    url.hostname,
    url.pathname,
    url.protocol === 'https:'
  );
  const cookies = this.jar.getCookies(access).toValueString();
  request_.cookies = cookies;
};
```

E.g.,

#### File *app.js*:

```js
const express = require('express');
const sessions = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(sessions({
  secret: "secretthatwillbeputinenv",
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
  resave: false
}));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.session.userId = 1;
  res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.get('/return', (req, res) => {
  console.log('userId: ', req.session.userId);
  if (req.session.userId) return res.json({ userId: req.session.userId });
  res.sendStatus(500)
})

module.exports = app;
```

#### File *app.test.js*:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const app = require('./app');

const agent = request.agent(app);

describe('76401408', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const res1 = await agent.get('/');
    expect(res1.headers["set-cookie"]).to.be.match(/connect.sid=/);
    const res2 = await agent.get('/return')
    expect(res2.body).to.be.eql({ userId: 1 })
  });
});
```

Test result:

```
  76401408
userId:  1
    ✓ should pass (101ms)


  1 passing (115ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   92.31 |       50 |     100 |   91.67 |
 app.js   |   92.31 |       50 |     100 |   91.67 | 20
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are experiencing this issue is that `supertest` makes separate HTTP requests for each `.get()`, `.post()`, etc. function call, and each of these requests are isolated and stateless. That is, they don't share cookies or sessions between them, like a real web browser would do.

`supertest` provides a way to "chain" requests, which keeps the cookies and can maintain the session. It involves creating an `agent` instance that you use to make requests.

You can do it this way:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');  // your express app

const agent = request.agent(app);

describe('my test', () => {
  it('should login and then access a protected route', async () => {
    await agent
      .post('/login')
      .send({ username: 'user', password: 'pass' })
      .expect(200);

    await agent
      .get('/protected')
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

`request.agent(app)` creates a `supertest` agent. This agent attaches cookies to the requests it makes, so it can maintain a session between multiple requests.

The `.post('/login')` call logs in the user. Because this is made with the agent, the login session is preserved.

The `.get('/protected')` call accesses a protected route. Because this is also made with the `agent`, it uses the session created by the previous login call.

This method does not require any hacks or mocks and should allow express-session to work correctly in your Jest tests.